# Online video sharing AS3 API

Tags: video, actionscript-3

I'm developing a web app based on videos that my client would like to upload using an online resource such as YouTube or Vimeo. Since YouTube has a 15 mn restriction length on the videos one can upload, my client has decided to use Vimeo instead, but Moogaloop(!) the Vimeo AS3 API is fairly restrictive and only offers a handful of methods to control the video.

What would be your best AS3 API for an online video sharing site? By best , I mean one that allows as much control as possible over the site's player features. I need to be able to listen to events , control the fullscreen capability , enable/disable some specific features such as a "embed" or "share" button.

Comment: Depending on the client's YouTube channel traffic, they may be able to get an elevated account from YouTube. If they're an educational institution, they can get one automatically.

Comment: They are actually , I thought they had checked this option already but will get back to them with this info. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client is willing to shell out a little dough, you should check out [Brightcove](http://www.brightcove.com/en/).  The amount of customization - both via API and web tools - is impressive, and you can host videos through them or on your own server.

Comment: Had a quick look at the AS3 API, and it already looks better than YT or Moogaloop. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It is pretty badass.  Anytime!

Answer (score 0):

This page contains the link to the EDU Program signup form which is just a Google Spreadsheet:

http://www.youtube.com/nonprofits

Comment: My client knew about it actually , their application was rejected. They advise educators but don't do any training themselves. Thanks for taking the time to post the link.